# when using backindicatorimage and backindicatortransitionmaskimage you must specify both a backindicatorimage and a backindicatortransitionmaskimage

Tags: uinavigationcontroller

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyDRc.png)

can't find the issue regarding this error in the back button